# same fd can be used in select for read and write

Tags: c, linux, select, linux-kernel, windows

I wish to use the same socket fd for both read and write operations. Lets say the "fd" is the one which I am working on then in that case

```
FD_SET(fd, &readfd);  
FD_SET(fd,&writefd);

select(fd+1, &readfd, &writefd, 0,200):
```

will hold good or it will return me the error.

I think since writefd and readfd are different sets the same fd can be set in both the sets.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks
Arpit

Thanks for quick responce .. Can I do the same behavior in poll POLLIN and POLLOUT to same fd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ok, and the proper way to monitor the same fd for both reading and writing. The last argument to select is a struct timeval though, not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Timeout value should be a struct timeval.

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 5;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
int iResult = select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL, &tv) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but if I remember correctly it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the same fd can be put in both the write and read set.

If you are receiving data on the fd, readfd will trigger and return.

If you are sending data on the fd, writefd will trigger when you have enough space in the buffer to send it.